# why ansible returns 'ansible_local' is undefined

Tags: ansible, task, roles

I have a problem with ansible_local variable:
I have the following facts.d defined on my ansible target

```sh
[role]
version=roles/version
```

I can access successfully to this fact with ansible setup module or with the following playbook

```
- name: "test"

  hosts: "{{ myhost }}"
  gather_facts: yes

  vars:

    my_role_path: "{{ ansible_local.test.role.version }}"

  tasks:

      - name: debug
        ansible.builtin.debug:
           msg: "{{ my_role_path }}"
```

stdout:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel8-test-2] => {
    "msg": "roles/version"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************
rhel8-test-2               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now, I want to use the var my_role_path to call a role called "echo" located in "my_role_path" folder of my ansible server.

I add the following statement:

```
 tasks:
    - name: debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ my_role_path }}"


  roles:

      - "{{ my_role_path }}/echo"
```

Now ansible returns :

```
ERROR! {{ ansible_local.test.role.version }}: 'ansible_local' is undefined
```

Is it a problem of namespace or scope of my variable ?  any clues are welcome.
Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static imports (`roles:` and `import_role`) happen at playbook parsing time, so all variables used for the action of importing (for example in the filename) have to be available at that point. Facts are gathered during playbook execution, so they cannot be used like this. (It *might* be possible to get this working by enabling fact caching and making sure the cache never expires, but that's a fragile prospect.)

You should instead use a [dynamic include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#including-roles-dynamic-reuse), which will be processed during execution instead of during parsing.

```yaml
 tasks:
    - name: debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ my_role_path }}"

    - ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: "{{ my_role_path }}/echo"
```

Comment: Thank you Flowerysong  !  it's working perfectly.